# React Native VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation

Tags: react-native

I know there are a lot of questions like this, but I tried a lot of different ways to solve this problem. I use a Scrollview, because it could be, that the screen is too big. The CustomC component is just a custom component. Than I have a `<FlatList />` for a few items.

Here is my code:

```
<ScrollView>
  <CustomC title="01" />
  <CustomC title="02" />
  <CustomC title="03" />
  <CustomC title="04" />
  <CustomC title="05" />
  <CustomC title="06" />
  <CustomC title="07" />
  <CustomC title="08" />
  <CustomC title="09" />
  <CustomC title="10" />


  <View>
    <FlatList keyExtractor = {item => item.id} data={exampleState} renderItem = {item => (<Text>{item.item.text}</Text>)} />              
  </View>

</ScrollView>
```

I tried for example to wrap my FlatList inside a `<View />` or a `<SafeAreaView />` but it didn't worked.

Than I tried to style the `<View />` and the `<SafeAreaView />` like this: `style={{flexDirection: "row", flex: 1}}`
Also didn't work :/

Comment: Why exactly do you need to use a `Flatlist` ?

Comment: Because I have a lot of Data; too large for ScrollView, but I need the CustomC components

Comment: Then why not have everything inside a `Flatlist`. Add 10 fake `0`s into your `exampleState` and then inside `renderItem`, render the `CustomC` for the first 10 elements and render `Text` for the items from `11` onwards. Would this work ?

Comment: Yeah, I think this would be a solution, but it's not really what I want :/ But thank you anyways for the idea! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is this:

```
<FlatList keyExtractor={(item) => "1"} data={[0]} renderItem={({item}) => (
  <CustomC title="01" />
  <CustomC title="02" />
  <CustomC title="03" />
  <CustomC title="04" />
  <CustomC title="05" />
  <CustomC title="06" />
  <CustomC title="07" />
  <CustomC title="08" />
  <CustomC title="09" />
  <CustomC title="10" />


  <View>
    <FlatList keyExtractor = {item => item.id} data={exampleState} renderItem = {item => (<Text>{item.item.text}</Text>)} />              
  </View>
)}>
</FlatList>
```